# Not able to add 3rd party software in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apt, ppa

I added a 3rd party software(terminator) PPA in Ubuntu 14.04 by running the command below:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gnome-terminator/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

And now, when I search for that package using:

```
sudo apt-cache search terminator
```

It doesn't show anything.

I wanted to know, why it is behaving like this ?

Comment: Did you use **sudo add-apt-repository** ppa... command or the one listed in your post **sudo apt-add-repository** ppa... which is a little bit changed and also wrong command? And don't forget to wait for the terminal windows's prompt to ask you to press Y for yes to finally add the desired ppa to your software sources list.

Comment: I used sudo apt-add-repository ppa... only.Yes, I waited for the prompt and typed yes after that.After this command got executed, ppa was added in a file under sources.list directory.It looks good but the package doesn't show when I try to install.

Comment: Unless you want older versions, use the one in the official repositories: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&keywords=terminator - you need to enable the universe repositoriy for it: http://askubuntu.com/a/148645/158442

Comment: Using one from the official repository worked.Thanks:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you want to add a 3rd party software then, go to the [Ubuntu official package site](http://packages.ubuntu.com/), search for the package, add the ppa from there and follow the normal steps as in:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update package-name
   sudo apt-get install package-name
   ```
2. You can also install 3rd party software without adding PPA also. Install the `gdebi` package first used for installing package from `.deb` file.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gdebi
   ```

   Go to the Ubuntu official package site, search for the package name, then you are given the url path there to get `.deb` file of that package. Download it Then install it using `gdebi`.

   ```
   sudo gdebi package-name.deb
   ```

Answer (score 4):

If you check the ppa [page](https://launchpad.net/~gnome-terminator/+archive/ubuntu/ppa), you'll notice that there's no package version available for trusty (14.04):

[image]

But you can install the `terminator` package from the Ubuntu [universe repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/terminator):

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe" 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install terminator
```

Comment: I hadn't seen the ubuntu version in the main terminator site.I searched for terminator in the official ubuntu site itself  and added from there, It worked:-)
                                                            sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main universe"

Answer (score 0):

Try these commands in a terminal window and see if they work for you:

```
      sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome-terminator

      sudo apt-get update

      sudo apt-get install terminator
```

I could not see any version of Terminator package built for Ubuntu 14.04 on [the official page](https://launchpad.net/~gnome-terminator/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) but if you still have problems with installing Terminator you can download latest version of Terminator from [this link](https://launchpad.net/~gnome-terminator/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+files/terminator_0.97_all.deb), and try installing it with GDEBI package manager rather than adding the ppa to your software sources list.

Comment: The whole point of adding ppa was to escape from dependency problem.I tried installing with gdebi, it works nicely with all the dependencies getting resolved.Thanks for the reply:-)

Comment: Good for you. You managed to solve the problem yourself. I run Ubuntu 12.04 so I was able to simply download **terminator_0.97_all.deb** package and install it with Gdebi. Gdebi solved the dependecies too while installing terminator package. You should post an answer to your own question in here and mark it as solved so other people benefit from your solution.